# Regexp capture words which NOT ends with A

Tags: regex

wordA - MUST NOT be captured

word - MUST be captured

This doesn't work....

```
\w+[^A]\b
```

Why?

Comment: Have you put brackets round it to create a capturing group?

Comment: Your regex is good. I've tryed it against some "test compiler" and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^A]` will match space:

```
hello world
^^^^^^
```

---

Try `look-behind`:

```
\w+(?<=[^A])\b
```

---

If you're working on english words, try this:

```
\w+[a-zB-Z_]\b
```

Comment: …or fall back to `\w*[^A\W]\b` if lookbehind is not supported

Comment: Bergi right, kev's solution works on gskinner.com but I need this in Qt, seems it doesn't support look-behind...

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative look-behind:

```
\w+\b(?<!A)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I found third way which seems works in my case:

```
\w+[^A\s]\b
```